# Стая - частный случай стада?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Можно ли относительно рыб, птиц вместо "стая" употреблять слово "стадо"? Стая - разновидность стада?

Answer (score 1):

С чисто биологической точки зрения **стадо** и **стая** являются полными синонимами и обозначают "любые крупные скопления животных".

В употреблении есть кое-какие различия. Стаи – **временные** объединения животных, которые проявляют биологически полезную организованность действий. Стаи облегчают выполнение каких-либо функций в жизни вида: добыча пищи, защита от врагов, миграции. Стайность наиболее широко распространена среди рыб и птиц, у млекопитающих – многих собачьих. В стаях сильно развиты подражательные реакции и ориентация на соседей.

Стада – **более длительные и постоянные объединения** животных по сравнению со стаями. Здесь осуществляются все основные функции жизни вида: добываемые корма, защита от хищников, миграции, размножение, воспитание молодняка и т. д. В основе группового поведения животных в стадах лежат взаимоотношения доминирования-подчинения, основанные на индивидуальных различиях между особями. Такая система взаимоотношений наиболее характерна для стадных млекопитающих, но в упрощенной форме встречается и у некоторых птиц.

Ответ на вопрос о соотношении слов надо искать в чисто языковой сфере - это просто "так говорится".

Если  мы заглянем в Этимологический словарь Макса Фасмера и посмотрим на их происхождение, то окажется, что "стая" первоначально значила "стойло", "стоянка" и происходит от слов "стать", "стоять". И слово "стадо" первоначально обозначало "стойло" и тоже произошло от "стать", "стоять". 
То есть и в языке стая и стадо являются синонимами и имеют общие корни! http://www.tavika.ru/2014/11/staya-stado.html

Стадо в Энциклопедическом словаре:

> Стадо - поголовье сельскохозяйственных животных одного вида
>   в хозяйстве.2) Группа животных одного вида, пола и возраста,
>   сформированная для откорма, пастьбы. 3) Группа диких, т. н. стадных,
>   животных одного вида со взаимосвязанным поведением (копытные,
>   китообразные и др.).

Значение слова Стадо по словарю Брокгауза и Ефрона:

> Стадо — временное собрание животных с различными целями. Процесс
>   образования С. получил название стадения (см. Собрания животных). В
>   состав С. входят по большей части животные одного вида, но могут быть
>   С. и из особей разных видов. К летающим животным, а также мелким
>   животным вообще в том же смысле применяется выражение — стая.

http://tolkslovar.ru/s11515.html

Заметили в Энциклопедическом словаре значение слова стадо - "поголовье"? Вот в этом значении вполне корректно употреблять слово стадо по отношению к птицам и рыбам, это уже термин:

> Под родительским стадом применительно к курам следует понимать такое
>   поголовье домашней птицы, которое содержится с целью получения
>   максимального количества высококачественных оплодотворённых яиц,
>   способных дать здоровое и жизнеспособное потомство.

https://agronomu.com/bok/7280-kormlenie-i-soderzhanie-roditelskogo-stada-kur-broylerov.html

Есть и понятие **рыбье стадо** - это о поголовье промысловых рыб. А вот примеры из литературы:

> "Волчье стадо ослабло, утратило волю к сопротивлению и в конце концов
>   очутилось в вольере - по соседству с зайцами". (В. В. Быков, "Лесное
>   счастье")
>
> "На перелёте стадо лебедей спустилось на Светлое озеро." (Д. Н.
>   Мамин-Сибиряк, "Приёмыш)

Comment: Найдите стаю слонов, найдите стадо перелетных птиц, найдите стаю управляемых людей.

Comment: Не вводите людей в заблуждение, они и так не могут выбраться из него.

Comment: Теперь две стайки мальчишек лезут на дерево, стараясь забраться как можно выше. Марина Тихонова, Тайник 21, 2015. Он медленно шёл по песку, и вскоре стайка мальчишек скрылась за поворотом.
С. В. Паршуткин, Снега моей души, 2018.Около заборчика расположилась шумная стайка мальчишек, живо обсуждавших происходящее действо. Андрей Сазонов, Розыгрыш
Стайка мальчишек, посмеиваясь, наблюдала за нами.
Т. В. Полякова, Найти, влюбиться и отомстить, 2013

Comment: О чём я и пишу: стая - собраны по собственной воле. Стайка мальчишек - это не управляемая группа.

Comment: В дикой природе стадами живут слоны (самки и дети, до 15 особей), сайгаки, бизоны, гориллы. Их-то кто сгонял в стадо? Это добровольные объединения. Так им легче жить - питаться, защищаться.

Comment: Уверены, что слово "стадо" используется правильно по отношению к слонам, сайгакам, бизонам, гориллам? Кто это слово употребил? Не в загоне ли или не в заповеднике перечисленные виды? Слово "стадо" может использоваться вместо "стая", но слово "стая" невозможно использовать вместо "стадо" (стая коров, стая лошадей, стая свиней, стая овец...).

Comment: . https://givotniymir.ru/slon-zhivotnoe-obraz-zhizni-i-sreda-obitaniya-slona/
https://obrazovanie.guru/nauka/biologiya/kakie-zhivotnye-zhivut-v-pustyne-na-territorii-rossii.html
 https://22oa.ru/kto-zhivet-v-stepi-zhivotnye/
http://country-in-africa.ru/gorilla.php
Так уж сложилось, что стая употребляется по отношению к летающим и волкам, а стадо - к парнокопытным и ещё некоторым видам животных. "Стая" вместо "стадо" никто и не скажет, а вот наоборот - вполне возможно.

Comment: Вы забыли про рыб. Они могут быть свободными - в реке (это стая) и искусственно выведенными - это стадо. "Стая" употребляется и к антилопам, оленям, зубрам если таковые вне загона, вне заповедника. Два разных слова - два разных понятия. Это русский язык.

Answer (score -1):

А попробуйте: стадо рыб, стадо птиц, стадо волков, попробуйте стаю коров, стаю лошадей, стаю овец - как вам, гожа такая небывальщина? 
Рыбы, птицы, волки - собираются в стаю по собственной воле. В стадо же сгоняют против воли или держат в загонах, заповедниках против воли. Отсюда и: "управляемая толпа людей - стадо".

Comment: Ну, не знаю. По прошлому опыту помню, что советовать смотреть словари не помогает. Может, стоит попробовать просто почитать что-нибудь хороших писателей? Не тех, которые пишут только про "стада — управляемые толпы".

Comment: Что не так? В словарях этого разъяснения нету, поэтому вы в ступоре? Ещё раз прочитайте объяснение и скажите, где неточность или вымысел?

Comment: Представится возможность, расскажу вам что такое лженаука и как нынешние правила русского языка чётко вписываются в это понятие - лженаука.